# Connect to mysql on correct port JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, server

hey using a javascript app im making as a backend server for my website i keep getting this as an error when trying to connect to my mysql server.

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to win2k16-mcdmz:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
```

and this is my script to connect to the server. is there any ideas on why it is set to 1433?

```
private initializeServer() {
        const config = {
            user: 'MCAdmin',
            password: '*******',
            server: 'win2k16-mcdmz',
            port: 3306,
            database: 'ValorantLFG',
            encrypt: true
        };
        mysql.connect(config, (err) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }

            this.init.lfgRequestsTimeout();
            //this.init.noticesTimeout();
        });
    }
```

Comment: because its running  different piece of code would be my assumption.

Comment: @danblack shouldn't be, this server runs off port 3000, listening form 2464(i think) and connecting to 3306. only problem is its not connecting to that port

Comment: Do you have your SSL certificate ready? you enable the 'SSL' by `encrypt: true`

Comment: you didn't `var mysql = require('mssql')` rather than `mysql`? 1433 is the MSSQL port.